# Adding a new Coveragestore in a certain Workspace by REST

Tags: geoserver, raster, rest

So, simple thing as it seems but I can't seem to make it work! I'm trying to add a raster data file (GeoTIFF) to geoserver via REST API, using curl on linux. REST API *is* working, since I created a new workspace using it:

```
curl -u admin:geoserver -v -XPOST -H 'Content-type: text/xml' \
 -d '<workspace><name>restProba</name></workspace>' \
 http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces
```

It's correctly created as shown by Geoserver's admin ui, but when I try to add a coveragestore to that workspace by executing

```
curl -u admin:geoserver -v -XPOST -H 'Content-type: text/xml' -d
'<coverageStore><name>int_dec</name><enabled>true</enabled>
<type>GeoTIFF</type> <url>$home/int_dec.tif</url></coverageStore>'     
"http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/restProba/coveragestores?configure=all"
```

even though it is correctly loaded, it goes directly into the default workspace, which is not the one I want it in. Is there any way of defining which workspace i want it in? I thought it'd enough by mentioning it in the URL where I point to restProba's workspace URI but it seems to be omiting it.

Thanks for your help :-)

pd: newbie with geoserver, I've tried searching for this but either i'm not using the correct search criteria, im a fool or it's just too simple for anyone to ask that i'm even fooler for asking it :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you can try this after creating the workspace:

```
curl -u admin:geoserver -v -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' \
     -d '<coverageStore><name>int_dec</name><workspace>restProba</workspace>  
         <enabled>true</enabled></coverageStore>' \
         http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/restProba/coveragestores
```

It should create a coveragestore called `int_dec` in the `restProba` workspace::

You can then reference the GeoTIFF file:

```
curl -u admin:geoserver -v -XPUT -H 'Content-type: text/plain' \
     -d 'file:/$home/int_dec.tif' \
      http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/restProba/coveragestores/int_dec/external.geotiff?configure=first\&coverageName=int_dec
```

---

I think your problem is the missing `'`

Your request was:

```
curl -u admin:geoserver -v -XPOST -H 'Content-type: text/xml' -d
<coverageStore><name>int_dec</name><enabled>true</enabled>
<type>GeoTIFF</type> <url>$home/int_dec.tif</url></coverageStore>'     
"http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/restProba/coveragestores?configure=all"
```

It should've been:

```
curl -u admin:geoserver -v -XPOST -H 'Content-type: text/xml' -d
'<coverageStore><name>int_dec</name><enabled>true</enabled>
<type>GeoTIFF</type> <url>$home/int_dec.tif</url></coverageStore>'     
"http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/restProba/coveragestores?configure=all"
```

Comment: Checked it and nope, I did the request properly. Good catch tho, I'll correct the question :) (im kind of relieved it wasn't that, I'd be humiliated!)

Comment: At least your problem will be solved ;-) Updated my answer. I hope it will work now.

Answer (score 1):

To add a GeoTIFF store and a layer of the same name in one step you can execute:

```
$ curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPUT -H "Content-type: text/plain"
       -d "file:///path_to_directory/int_dec.tif"
       http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/restProba/coveragestores/int_dec/external.geotiff
```

More details in the ["REST configuration examples: Adding an existing shapefile"](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/examples/curl.html#adding-an-existing-shapefile).