# Creating Coveragestore GeoTIFF using REST API

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

I need to create a layer by uploading a GeoTIFF file.

After reading [Adding a new Coveragestore in a certain Workspace by REST](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37779/adding-a-new-coveragestore-in-a-certain-workspace-by-rest) and [Programming Geoserver 2.0.2 to add a raster data store and layer without the UI](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6479/programming-geoserver-2-0-2-to-add-a-raster-data-store-and-layer-without-the-ui) I create a method to do this using Java.

My problem is after creating the workspace and when trying to create the store (using PUT) my server returns error 500. The Geoserver Log:

```
        Version = 1.3.0
        Request = GetMap
        Get = true
        RawKvp = {REQUEST=GetMap, FORMAT=image/png, CRS=EPSG:3857, BBOX=-4852834.05176927,-2661231.576776698,-4696291.017841228,-2504688.5428486574, VERSION=1.3.0, STYLES=, SERVICE=WMS, WIDTH=256, HEIGHT=256, TRANSPARENT=true, LAYERS=osm:AA_OpenStreetMap}
        BaseUrl = http://10.5.115.122:80/geoserver/
        RequestCharset = UTF-8
2016-11-17 11:21:41,742 ERROR [geoserver.rest] - No such layer: Carta_puntarenas
2016-11-17 11:21:41,742 ERROR [geoserver.rest] -
org.geoserver.rest.RestletException
        at org.geoserver.catalog.rest.LayerFinder.findTarget(LayerFinder.java:39)
        at org.restlet.Finder.handle(Finder.java:268)
        at org.geoserver.rest.BeanDelegatingRestlet.handle(BeanDelegatingRestlet.java:38)
        at org.restlet.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:105)
        at org.restlet.Filter.handle(Filter.java:134)
        at org.restlet.Router.handle(Router.java:444)
        at org.geoserver.rest.RESTDispatcher$1.handle(RESTDispatcher.java:205)
        at com.noelios.restlet.ext.servlet.ServletConverter.service(ServletConverter.java:129)
```

The 3 steps method in second post is more convenient but I have no way to send the file to the server and can't fill the `URL` store attribute.

The 2 steps of first post is what I'm doing since I can send a `PUT` and hope the Geoserver can resolve the `URL` itself (don't know where the file will be stored) but the `create layer` part was not shown.

The ported Java code to PUT is like this:

```
public int doPutFile( File file, String contentType, String url, String content, String geoUser, String geoPassword ) throws Exception {
    int code = 0;

    String geoCreds = geoUser + ":" + geoPassword;
    String encodedAuth = new String( Base64.encodeBase64( geoCreds.getBytes() ) );
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL( url ).openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod( "PUT" );
    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedAuth );
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-type", contentType);
    con.setConnectTimeout( 120000 );

    con.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStream outputStream = con.getOutputStream();
    FileInputStream streamFileInputStream = new FileInputStream( file );
    BufferedInputStream streamFileBufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(streamFileInputStream);     

    byte[] streamFileBytes = new byte[ 512 ];
    int bytesRead = 0;

    while ((bytesRead = streamFileBufferedInputStream.read(streamFileBytes)) > 0) {
        outputStream.write(streamFileBytes, 0, bytesRead);
    }       
    outputStream.flush();

    code = con.getResponseCode();

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = con.getInputStream();
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, writer, "UTF-8");
        String theString = writer.toString();
        inputStream.close();

        System.out.println( theString );

    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       

    con.disconnect();
    streamFileBufferedInputStream.close();
    return code;        
}
```

and the code to POST:

```
public int doRESTRequest( String requestMethod, String url, String content, String geoUser, String geoPassword ) throws Exception {
    int code = 0;

    String geoCreds = geoUser + ":" + geoPassword;
    String encodedAuth = new String( Base64.encodeBase64( geoCreds.getBytes() ) );
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL( url ).openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod( requestMethod );
    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedAuth );
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/xml");

    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.getOutputStream().write( content.getBytes("UTF-8") );
    code = con.getResponseCode();

    // To use with GET method
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = con.getInputStream();
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, writer, "UTF-8");
        String theString = writer.toString();
        inputStream.close();
        //System.out.println( "WebClient:doPostStream >>> " + theString );
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }

    con.disconnect();
    return code;

}
```

... and to upload and create the TIFF Layer:

```
StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
postData.append("<coverageStore>");
postData.append("<name>" + storeName + "</name>");
postData.append("<workspace>" + workspaceName + "</workspace>");
postData.append("<enabled>true</enabled>");
postData.append("<description>Some description</description>");
postData.append("<type>GeoTIFF</type>");
postData.append("<srs>EPSG:4326</srs><projectionPolicy>REPROJECT_TO_DECLARED</projectionPolicy>");
postData.append("</coverageStore>");

String serverRESTAPIStore = geoserverURL + "rest/workspaces/" + workspaceName + "/coveragestores";
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
resp = wc.doRESTRequest( "POST", serverRESTAPIStore, postData.toString(), geoUser, geoPassword );           



String serverRESTAPI = geoserverURL + "rest/workspaces/" + workspaceName + "/coveragestores/" + storeName + "/external.geotiff?configure=first&coverageName=" + storeName;
int result = wc.doPutFile( file, "geotif/geotiff", serverRESTAPI, "", geoUser, geoPassword );
```

The tiff file is named `Carta_puntarenas.tif` and have 75MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

First: I can do it in just one step:

```
String serverRESTAPI = geoserverURL + "rest/workspaces/" + workspaceName + "/coveragestores/" + storeName + "/external.geotiff?configure=first&coverageName=" + storeName;
int result = wc.doPutFile( file, "geotif/geotiff", serverRESTAPI, "", geoUser, geoPassword );
```

Sending the file is enough to create the store.

Other:
The file name `must`be `file.geotiff`. I don't know why. So I changed to

```
String serverRESTAPI = geoserverURL + "rest/workspaces/" + workspaceName + 
                "/coveragestores/" + storeName + "/file.geotiff";
```

All working now.

Comment: because if you use the parameter `file.tif` it tells GeoServer you are sending a tif file - if you used file.png it would expect a png file

Comment: I'm thinking the `Content-type` is controlling this. But makes sense.

Comment: content-type could be application/zip for example

Comment: Oh yes? Can I pass a zipped geotiff file when creating the coverage store? Cool!

Comment: Zipping should make no difference to a compressed tif, but could package a tif plus world file.

Answer (score 2):

2020 update,

Using [geoserver-rest](https://pypi.org/project/geoserver-rest/) library(`pip install geoserver-rest`). The example case is below,

```py
#import and initialize library
from geo.Geoserver import Geoserver
geo = Geoserver('http://localhost:8080/geoserver', username='admin', password='geoserver')


#Create/upload coveragestore (raster data)
geo.create_coveragestore(lyr_name='layer1' path=r'path\to\raster\file.tif', workspace='demo')
```