# Are .mbtiles supported in the current GeoServer REST API?

Tags: geoserver, mbtiles

Saw that there was a pull request for GeoServer to support .mbtiles in the REST API.

Is this currently supported?

Comment: Can you please drop the link where you actually saw that PR?

Comment: if the PR was merged then it is supported, if not merged then it is not supported.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/pull/4191

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 2):

The PR refer tos https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-9576, which is marked as fixed 2.17.1 onwards.

Mind, it talks about a MBTiles store, not a MBTiles reader. It means, there is support for uploading a MBTiles file full of vector tiles, that PR did not add support for MBTiles full of rasters.

Checking the code, it would seem the latter had been supported already (e.g., earlier than 2.17.1), but I haven't used it personally, so can't confirm.

Comment: I cannot find any documentation on how to use the REST API for uploading mbtiles for rasters. Can anyone provide an example (Maybe a curl example?) or point me to some documentation? Thank you very much!

Comment: I believe there is no documentation. I think you can follow the lead of this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252004/unable-to-publish-a-geotiff-file-in-geoserver-with-curl-tool  Replace ".geotiff" with ".mbtiles" in the curl. The mime type is likely not used by the code but.. did not try it.